# The OdbcParameterCollection only accepts non-null OdbcParameter type objects

Tags: c#, .net, exception, ado.net, odbc

Just as a little heads up, I'm completely new to this whole "coding" thing in general, so forgive me if I don't make myself clear and just let me know if I can tell you anything else. I've been Googling for days and couldn't find anything, I'm not sure if that's just bad on my part, or just because I'm really new and wouldn't know the solution if it were right in front of my face.

When I go to test the application (Visual Studio 2010), everything shows up and I can put in information in my text boxes, but once I press submit, this error pops up:

> "The OdbcParameterCollection only accepts non-null OdbcParameter type objects. Parameter name: value"

and it points to this line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
```

I don't know if I'm setting the parameters wrong or INSERT INTO statement wrong or what. I can show you the ASP.net code also if needed. Let me know if I can give you any more info! Thank you in advanced!

My C# code is this:

```
 private void execution(string eventspecialist, string phone, string phone2, string firstname, string lastname, string besttime, string companyname, string nonprofit, string requesteddate, string requestedtime, string attendance, string eventtype, string other, string leadsource, string notes, string catering, string bar, string damagedeposit, string dancefloor)
{


    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(GetConnectionString());

    string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (eventspecialist, phone, phone2, firstname, lastname, besttime, companyname, nonprofit, requesteddate, requestedtime, attendance, eventtype, other, leadsource, notes, catering, bar, damagedeposit, dancefloor) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPECIALIST", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventspecialist;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE1", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE2", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone2;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_FNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = firstname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_LNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lastname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BEST_TIME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = besttime;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY_NAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = companyname;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NONPROFIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = nonprofit;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_DATE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 10).Value = requesteddate;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_TIME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 20).Value = requestedtime;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ATTENDANCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = attendance;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EVENT_TYPE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventtype;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_DESC", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = other;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LEAD_SOURCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = leadsource;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NOTES", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = notes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CATERING", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = catering;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BAR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = bar;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DAMAGE_DEPOSIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = damagedeposit;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DANCE_FLOOR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = dancefloor;



        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException ex_msg)
    {

        string msg = "Error occured while inserting";
        msg += ex_msg.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {

        conn.Close();
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    execution(eventspecialist.Text, phone.Text, phone2.Text, firstname.Text, lastname.Text, besttime.SelectedItem.Text, companyname.Text, nonprofit.Text, requesteddate.Text, requestedtime.Text, attendance.Text, eventtype.SelectedItem.Text, other.Text, leadsource.SelectedItem.Text, notes.Text, catering.Text, bar.Text, damagedeposit.Text, dancefloor.SelectedItem.Text);

    conform.Visible = true;
    Control frm = this.FindControl("form1");
    foreach (Control ctrl in frm.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
        {
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = "";
        }
        else if (ctrl is CheckBox)
        {
            ((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked = false;
        }
        else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
        {
            ((DropDownList)ctrl).SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which database server are you using mysql???

Comment: I'm using an ODBC Data Source for SQL Server Native Client 10.0. If that's what you were asking?

Comment: Why are you not using the SqlClient?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Comment: Because whenever I used that it gives me an error that said "keyword 'dsn' not supported", which after searching online someone recommended I used ODBC instead. Not sure if that was a wise decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a null reference because you've created and set the size of `pram` but have not added any objects to it. So, what you have is an array filled with nulls. It looks like you can eliminate the `for` loop and the `pram` array altogether, because you're adding the parameters to `cmd` already, outside the loop.

The following code is unnecessary:

```
OdbcParameter[] pram = new OdbcParameter[19];
```

and also

```
for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
}
```

Additionally, you should set the values of each parameter in this fashion:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPECIALIST", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventspecialist;
```

So, your `try` block will look like this:

```
try
{
    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPECIALIST", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventspecialist;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE1", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE2", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone2;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_FNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = firstname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_LNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lastname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BEST_TIME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = besttime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY_NAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = companyname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NONPROFIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = nonprofit;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_DATE", OdbcType.Date, 10).Value = requesteddate;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_TIME", OdbcType.Time, 20).Value = requestedtime;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ATTENDANCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = attendance;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EVENT_TYPE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventtype;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_DESC", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = other;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LEAD_SOURCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = leadsource;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NOTES", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = notes;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CATERING", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = catering;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BAR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = bar;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DAMAGE_DEPOSIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = damagedeposit;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DANCE_FLOOR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = dancefloor;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

From your question's edit, I see this is the code you're using, and I take it you're still getting the same error? This most likely means that one of the values you're adding to the parameters collection is null. If you inspect them with the debugger, do they all have values set?

**Edit, again:**

There's another error which I missed before. The SQL command you've written for ODBC is using parameters incorrectly, as indicated by the new error.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (eventspecialist, phone, phone2, firstname, lastname, besttime, companyname, nonprofit, requesteddate, requestedtime, attendance, eventtype, other, leadsource, notes, catering, bar, damagedeposit, dancefloor) 
VALUES (@SPECIALIST, @CUST_PHONE1, @CUST_PHONE2, @CUST_FNAME, @CUST_LNAME, @BEST_TIME, @COMPANY_NAME, @NONPROFIT, @REQ_DATE, @REQ_TIME, @ATTENDANCE, @EVENT_TYPE, @OTHER_DESC, @LEAD_SOURCE, @NOTES, @CATERING, @BAR, @DAMAGE_DEPOSIT, @DANCE_FLOOR)";
```

Should be:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (eventspecialist, phone, phone2, firstname, lastname, besttime, companyname, nonprofit, requesteddate, requestedtime, attendance, eventtype, other, leadsource, notes, catering, bar, damagedeposit, dancefloor) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Please note that I've broken up the line of code for readability. Also, the order you add your parameters to the collection matters. They need to be in the order that matches the columns (The value for `eventspecialist` must be first, the one for `phon` second, etc.) It may also be the case that you need to name your parameters the same as the column names, as @shahkalpesh suggests.

ODBC commands use `?` to access parameters, rather than the parameter name as SQL commands do. A couple links on the subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dcw81x5.aspx

**Edit**

I notice you're passing all the values to the method as `string`. You'll need to convert those to the correct type, and use the correct ODBC data type, when adding parameters. Please see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbctype.aspx) for ODBC parameter types.

Use whatever type the column is (`varchar`, `money`, etc), and if your variables (`eventspecialist`, etc) are not of the correct type, convert the values to the correct type (as indicated in the link) before adding them. For example, `cmd.Parameters.Add("@ATTENDANCE", OdbcType.Int).Value = Int32.Parse(attendance);`. Please note that `Int32.Parse` may throw an error if `attendance` is not a string which represents an integer. I suggest changing the method signature to require the correct types, then validating and converting them before the call to `execution`. This will avoid type conversion errors in this method. That way, if you do get an error here, you know it's related to the interaction with the DB, rather than setting up the command incorrectly.

Comment: So just to make sure, you mean removing for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
        } 
and what else?

Comment: Yes, you can remove that whole for loop. Since you haven't put anything in to the pram array, you won't get anything out of it, and that's where the null value comes from. But, since you're manually adding the parameters to the command (cmd.Parameters.Add(...); and cmd.Parameters["xxx"].Value = xxx;) you don't need to add them again. You can also remove the line OdbcParameter[] pram = new OdbcParameter[19]; I've edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: @Kruce: Remove `OdbcParameter[]` and all its usage. Use `.Value = x` instead.

Comment: Where would I put .Value = x, just anywhere that OdbcParameter[] is? So for example ".Value pram = new .Value = 19"? Or was that just going in the entire wrong direction?

Comment: You would add `.Value = x` to every `cmd.Parameters.Add(...);` line, and remove every `cmd.Parameters["@x"].Value = x;` line. I'll edit my answer with a complete example.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I've done that and edited my code now, I just get this error: Error occured while insertingERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@SPECIALIST".

Comment: @Kruce: I assume you will have to name the parameters same as the column name, to start with. Please look at the answer, I have written above.

Comment: Do you mean the example that shows: cmd.Parameters.Add("eventspecialist", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);

I understand that, but how would I connect that to my actual database @SPECIALIST?

Comment: @Kruce I have updated my answer to address the new error you're getting.

Comment: I originally had the "?, ?, ?, ?, etc." but changed based on the answers. I believe that everything is in the right order. The new error I'm getting is "ERROR [42S22] Invalid column name 'eventspecialist'" Which also repeats for all the other ones too.So when you say name my parameters the same as the column, you're suggesting renaming "eventspecialist" to "SPECILAIST"?

Comment: Stick with the `?` usage. Not having that was causing the `Must declare the scalar variable "@SPECIALIST"` error. What does your table definition look like? That error suggests that the `tblcontacts` table does not have a column named `eventspecialist`. I believe shahkalpesh's suggestion is to change `@SPECIALIST` to `eventspecialist` in the line `cmd.Parameters.Add(@SPECIALIST, ...`

Comment: No, my table column name is SPECIALIST, 'eventspecialist' is the name of textbox where the user puts info that I want sent to my table. Am I doing that completely wrong?

Comment: @Kruce - ah, yes. You should use the column names there rather than the textbox names. So it should be `string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (SPECIALIST, ...`

Comment: Ahh, I think that may have just done it. I'm getting little errors now like Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Decimal. But I believe that's because I'm declaring everything as NVarChar when some things are "numeric" or "money" Do you have any suggestions on that while I'm still in your help? Also, thanks for the patience.

Comment: @Kruce I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was really, really helpful. Like I said before I'm super new to all of this so do you have an easy way to explain how to actually "convert to the correct type" or "changing the method signature to require the correct types, then validating and converting them before the call to execution". Seriously again, thanks for the help. I don't want you to feel like you need to baby me through this all, but any help is extraordinarily appreciated. :)

Comment: Also, DANCE_FLOOR is money, but that's not an ODBC.Type?

Comment: No problem, everybody was new once. I would try `decimal` for the ODBC type for the `DANCE_FLOOR` parameter. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx for a run-down on the basics of converting your strings to the appropriate types. For now, I would just convert them inside the `execution` method. Once you get everything working, move the conversions outside to improve the structure and change the method to `execute(string eventspecialist, ... , decimal dancefloor, etc)`.

Comment: Oh boy, this is just a whole different problem I'll have to work on figuring! Lol! Thanks for all the help everyone in this question and Esoteric. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you've defined an array (`OdbcParameter[] pram = new OdbcParameter[19];`). But, you are not initializing elements of it.

Looking at your code, the following lines in your code is not required.

```
OdbcParameter[] pram = new OdbcParameter[19];
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
}
```

**EDIT**: I have't used `Odbc`* classes in the past.
Looking at the *specific* example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dcw81x5.aspx), your parameter name should be same as your column name

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("eventspecialist", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("phone", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("phone2", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("firstname", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("lastname", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("besttime", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50);
```

and so on for the rest of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add the Parameter with a value defined, presuming the values you are passing are not null where not specified.

Depending on the Database your parameters names in yoru query must match the parameters names defined in the OdbcParameters collection, and in some instances be in the correct order or application.

As per your update, specify your parameter names in your Query.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (eventspecialist, phone, phone2, firstname, lastname, besttime, companyname, nonprofit, requesteddate, requestedtime, attendance, eventtype, other, leadsource, notes, catering, bar, damagedeposit, dancefloor) VALUES (@EVENTSPECIALIST, @CUST_PHONE1, ETC ETC ETC)"; 


// Remove this code.
OdbcParameter[] pram = new OdbcParameter[19]; 

for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++) 
    { 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]); 
    } 


// Add your parameters with a value.
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPECIALIST", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventSpecialist;
```

I would also recommend using one of the Native Database connection classes where applicable, System.Data.SqlClient, MySql.Data.Client or the Oracle client.

Comment: @Esoteric Screen Name why don't you add a complete sensible answer yourself instead comments.

Comment: @Esoter: Please be more friendly on SO

Comment: I did this but got a different error "Error occured while insertingERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@SPECIALIST". Could it be because I should be switching the parameters? What I mean is "eventspecialist" is the string in my asp.net code and SPECIALIST is the database name I want that text box binded to.

Comment: Again, truly forgive me if I'm not making any sense at all, because I could be saying this all wrong. I appreciate any and all form of help that anyone can give.

Comment: Can you update your code in the Question then we can see what you've done?

Comment: I just updated what I've changed based on what everyone's said. Let me know if you see anything.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this if you already added parameters in command object.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pram.Length; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(pram[i]);
}
```

no need of this to do again and also change the

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tblcontacts (eventspecialist) VALUES (@SPECIALIST)"
```

in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SPECIALIST", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventspecialist;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE1", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_PHONE2", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = phone2;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_FNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = firstname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CUST_LNAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = lastname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BEST_TIME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = besttime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY_NAME", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = companyname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NONPROFIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = nonprofit;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_DATE", OdbcType.Date, 10).Value = requesteddate;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@REQ_TIME", OdbcType.Time, 20).Value = requestedtime;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ATTENDANCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = attendance;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EVENT_TYPE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = eventtype;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OTHER_DESC", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = other;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@LEAD_SOURCE", OdbcType.NVarChar, 50).Value = leadsource;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NOTES", OdbcType.NVarChar, 225).Value = notes;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CATERING", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = catering;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BAR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 1).Value = bar;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DAMAGE_DEPOSIT", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = damagedeposit;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DANCE_FLOOR", OdbcType.NVarChar, 19).Value = dancefloor;
```